# How to return a HttpResponseException on webpage from HttpModule

Tags: c#, asp.net, api

I am trying to return a message from and invalid API call but can't seem to get the message displayed, also the code in my controller executes regradless.The "VerifyKey" method is in a HttpModule that executes  on every request. I would like to be able run the method and just write the error to the web page and stop all execution.

```
public HttpResponseMessage VeryifyKey(string partnerKey, OdataService myService)
{
    var response = new HttpResponseMessage();
    response.StatusCode = (HttpStatusCode)403;

    if (partnerKey != null)
    {
        var isPartnerValid = myService.IsPartnerValid(partnerKey);

        if (!isPartnerValid)
        {
            response.ReasonPhrase = "Your  partner access key appears to be disabled or invalid";
            throw new HttpResponseException(response);

        }
    }
    else
    {
        response.ReasonPhrase = "Your Url did not include a  partner key";
        throw new HttpResponseException(response);
    }

    return response;
}
```

Instead of getting the message I get the following exception:

> Processing of the HTTP request resulted in an exception. Please see the HTTP response returned by the 'Response' property of this exception for details.

How can I just return the exception message on the webpage?

Answer (score 0):

What I would recommend you to do is let the Http StatusCode reflect the outcome of you call. So for instance:

```
Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK,"Everything in order");
```

or

```
Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Your key was missing");
```

Then you need to start handling these kind of errors on the JavaScript side of things ( assuming you are using some sort of AJAX call ).

Comment: Im actually doing the key validation in HttpModule using the OnAuthenticateRequest ..not sure how to write to webpage